# C# Compact-Framework friendly command line parser

Tags: compact-framework, parsing, windows-ce, command-line-arguments

I read this question: [Command Line Parser for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631410/looking-for-a-command-line-argument-parser-for-net).

I thought that was what I was looking for, but the library [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) is not Compact framework friendly...

I *REALLY* don't want to write a CL parser and I have been drifting away from the real purpose of my little app because of this unfortunate trial.

Does someone know of a library that fits the compact-framework? (preferably with simplicity and functionality like the one mentioned above)
Does not matter whether version 2 or 3.5

Comment: What sort of device/OS are you intending to run this on? After all, you need to have a command prompt to run the command from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm using.  I borrowed it from somewhere, but not sure where:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
/// Parses the command line arguments into a name/value collection
/// </summary>
public class CommandLineArgumentParser
{
    #region Fields
    private StringDictionary parameters;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CommandLineArgumentParser"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">command-line arguments
    /// </param>
    public CommandLineArgumentParser(string[] args)
    {
        this.parameters = new StringDictionary();
        Regex spliter = new Regex(@"^-{1,2}|^/|=|:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        Regex remover = new Regex(@"^['""]?(.*?)['""]?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        string parameter = null;
        string[] parts;

        // Valid parameters forms:
        // {-,/,--}param{ ,=,:}((",')value(",'))
        // Examples: 
        // -param1 value1 --param2 /param3:"Test-:-work" 
        //   /param4=happy -param5 '--=nice=--'
        foreach (string txt in args)
        {
            // Look for new parameters (-,/ or --) and a
            // possible enclosed value (=,:)
            parts = spliter.Split(txt, 3);

            switch (parts.Length)
            {
                // Found a value (for the last parameter 
                // found (space separator))
                case 1:
                    if (parameter != null)
                    {
                        if (!this.parameters.ContainsKey(parameter))
                        {
                            parts[0] = remover.Replace(parts[0], "$1");

                            this.parameters.Add(parameter, parts[0]);
                        }

                        parameter = null;
                    }

                    // else Error: no parameter waiting for a value (skipped)
                    break;

                // Found just a parameter
                case 2:
                    // The last parameter is still waiting. 
                    // With no value, set it to true.
                    if (parameter != null)
                    {
                        if (!this.parameters.ContainsKey(parameter))
                        {
                            this.parameters.Add(parameter, "true");
                        }
                    }

                    parameter = parts[1];
                    break;

                // Parameter with enclosed value
                case 3:
                    // The last parameter is still waiting. 
                    // With no value, set it to true.
                    if (parameter != null)
                    {
                        if (!this.parameters.ContainsKey(parameter))
                        {
                            this.parameters.Add(parameter, "true");
                        }
                    }

                    parameter = parts[1];

                    // Remove possible enclosing characters (",')
                    if (!this.parameters.ContainsKey(parameter))
                    {
                        parts[2] = remover.Replace(parts[2], "$1");
                        this.parameters.Add(parameter, parts[2]);
                    }

                    parameter = null;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // In case a parameter is still waiting
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            if (!this.parameters.ContainsKey(parameter))
            {
                this.parameters.Add(parameter, "true");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a count of command line arguments
    /// </summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameters.Count;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value with the given parameter name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">name of the parameter</param>
    /// <returns>the value of the parameter</returns>
    public string this[string param]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameters[param];
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look later today

Comment: [Source](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3111/c-net-command-line-arguments-parser).

Answer (score 2):

**I developed this framework, maybe it helps:**

The SysCommand is a powerful cross-platform framework, to develop Console Applications in .NET. Is simple, type-safe, and with great influences of the MVC pattern.

https://github.com/juniorgasparotto/SysCommand

```
namespace Example.Initialization.Simple
{
    using SysCommand.ConsoleApp;

    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            return App.RunApplication();
        }
    }

    // Classes inheriting from `Command` will be automatically found by the system
    // and its public properties and methods will be available for use.
    public class MyCommand : Command
    {
        public void Main(string arg1, int? arg2 = null)
        {
            if (arg1 != null)
                this.App.Console.Write(string.Format("Main arg1='{0}'", arg1));
            if (arg2 != null)
                this.App.Console.Write(string.Format("Main arg2='{0}'", arg2));
        }

        public void MyAction(bool a)
        {
            this.App.Console.Write(string.Format("MyAction a='{0}'", a));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Tests:**

```
// auto-generate help
$ my-app.exe help

// method "Main" typed
$ my-app.exe --arg1 value --arg2 1000

// or without "--arg2"
$ my-app.exe --arg1 value

// actions support
$ my-app.exe my-action -a
```

Comment: Whenever you link to a blog post, library, or other external resource you're involved in, [you must clearly indicate this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 0):

http://commandline.codeplex.com/  I've used this so many times I've lost count.  Maybe it works for CE.  If not, it'll provide a fantastic starting point.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the exact one I am having trouble with. Maybe it{s because of me, though I don{t think so. The project answer exactly to my needs. I wish it worked without problems under Windows CE...